# Itterating through a list of objects from custom made class

Tags: python, object, pygame, iteration

I am writing a chess game and I have encountered a problem.

I have created figure classes (Pawn, Tower, Jumper, Runner, King and Queen), now I am trying to make add some functionality so that the program recognizes when the mouse cursor is over a figure, and that's where my problems begin.

Obviously, I can make it work if by hand I write a check for each single instance of a class (for example 16 pawn), like so:

[Notice **Pawn is my class name**]

```
mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if pawn1.start_x <=  mouse_x <= pawn1.start_x + 86 and pawn1.start_y + 84 >= mouse_y >= pawn1.start_y:
        print('Pawn 1 was clicked')
```

This is tedious, I want to iterate through a list of all existing pawns;

```
pawn_list = [pawn1, pawn2, pawn3, pawn4, pawn5, pawn6, pawn7, pawn8, pawn9, pawn10, pawn11, pawn12, pawn12, pawn14, pawn15, pawn16]
```

MY QUESTION IS HOW CAN I DO THAT?
Till now I have come up with the following:

```
    mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
     
    for Pawn in pawn_list:
        if pawn_list[Pawn].start_x <= pawn_list[Pawn].start_x + 86 and pawn_list[Pawn].start_y + 84 >= mouse_y >= pawn_list[Pawn].start_y:
            print('The mouse is over the pawn no:' + str(Pawn))
```

But then I get a following error:
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Pawn`

Nor does using a different variable name help me out:

```
for _ in range(len(pawn_list)):
        if pawn_list[_].start_x <= pawn_list[_].start_x + 86 and pawn_list[_].start_y + 84 >= mouse_y >= pawn_list[_].start_y:
            print('The mouse is over the pawn no:' + str(_))
```

All help is appreciated, thanks !!!

Comment: You're using your Class name ('Pawn') as a variable for each element in the list, while iterrating through it. That's probably causing your error. Try something like "for p in pawn_list"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already iterating through list, so why do you want to get the Pawn index from the list again? Potentially this is incorrect.

Correct statement would be:

```
for objPawn in pawn_list:
        if objPawn.start_x <= objPawn.start_x + 86 and objPawn.start_y + 84 >= mouse_y >= objPawn.start_y:
            print('The mouse is over the pawn no:' + str(Pawn))
```

Comment: Hi I have tried out what You have suggested. Unfortunately I get now an error:                                                     
pawn1 = Pawn(65, 730, 2)
TypeError: 'Pawn' object is not callable                                                                               Do You have any other ideas?

Comment: I updated variable in my solution. Please check if that helps. Class Pawn must have start_x and start_y  member variables for this solution to work.

Comment: The reason why I wanted to get the Pawn index was that I can then move the specific Pawn by editing its value start_x and start_y correspondingly.